# i want to set style to all children div using children method in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, children

**html code**

```
<div id="main">
<div id="one">Images</div>
<div id="two">Images</div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#main').children().css({"display":"none","position":"absolute"});
```

I want to hide all child elements in a div.
But it display all img.
this code is not working for me need some help.

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NeHfG/. Is your jQuery in a document ready call or at the end of the document?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){$('#main').children().css({"display":"none","position":"absolute"});});

Comment: You could try $("#main").children().hide(); //This only considers the display only

Comment: but i want to set it position to absolute

Comment: As you can see the code you posted works fine. Do you have other code that might be causing a conflict? Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: other code overwrite this code.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use only the `display: none;` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pGS44/1/

If selecting the DIVs not work, try to select `$("#main img").hide();`

Check if this works! :)